# What is the use of the @Temporal annotation in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

The Hibernate Documentation has the information below for the `@Temporal` annotation:

> In plain Java APIs, the temporal precision of time is not defined.
>   When dealing with temporal data you might want to describe the
>   expected precision in database. Temporal data can have DATE, TIME, or
>   TIMESTAMP precision (ie the actual date, only the time, or both). Use
>   the @Temporal annotation to fine tune that.

What does `temporal precision of time is not defined` mean? What is `temporal` data and its precision? How does it fine tune?

Comment: If you use Calendar as your Entity property then in plain java it prints a lot of information which is not necessary when you want to save it to database, for example.In that case, you can have something like @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)Calendar calendar in your entity to store timestamp to your database or just date or just time by changing  to @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE) or  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIME) on your Calendar property.

Comment: Since Hibernate 5 you don’t need and should not use `@Temporal` in new code. It was for annotating `Date` and `Calendar` fields, but those classes are poorly designed and long outdated Instead use classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). They have their *expected precision* built in, and you don’t use that annotation with them.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

This annotation must be specified for persistent fields or properties of type `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar`. It may only be specified for fields or properties of these types.

The `Temporal` annotation may be used in conjunction with the `Basic` annotation, the `Id` annotation, or the `ElementCollection` annotation (when the element collection value is of such a temporal type.

In plain Java APIs, the temporal precision of time is not defined. When dealing with temporal data, you might want to describe the expected precision in database. Temporal data can have DATE, TIME, or TIMESTAMP precision (i.e., the actual date, only the time, or both). Use the `@Temporal` annotation to fine tune that.

The temporal data is the data related to time. For example, in a content management system, the creation-date and last-updated date of an article are temporal data. In some cases, temporal data needs precision and you want to store precise date/time or both (`TIMESTAMP`) in database table.

The temporal  precision is not specified in core Java APIs. `@Temporal` is a `JPA` annotation that converts back and forth between timestamp and `java.util.Date`. It also converts `time-stamp` into time. For example, in the snippet below, `@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)` ***drops the time value and only preserves the date***.

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private java.util.Date creationDate;
```

As per javadocs,

> Annotation to declare an appropriate {@code TemporalType} on query
>   method parameters. Note that this annotation can only be used on
>   parameters of type {@link Date} with **default `TemporalType.DATE`**

[Information above collected from various sources]

Comment: Why can't I use it with the Java type Timestamp?

Comment: So if you're just using TemporalType.TIMESTAMP ... is there any point to using this annotation? Dates seem to work fine to this end without it..

Comment: how I can store in MySql DB in the  format as `yyyy-MM-dd`

Comment: @shantaram_t [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18364789/format-datetime) might help you

Comment: @ankur-singhal I have used `@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)` and 
`@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")` but it gives me **exception**  `failed to convert property value of type java.lang.string to required type java.util.date`  `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse error: Unable to parse 02/10/2017`

Comment: I have input : `02/10/2017` and want to convert it to `2017-10-02` or `2017/10/02`

Comment: What if I just need to use the year?

Answer (score 70):

**`@Temporal`** is a JPA annotation which can be used to store in the database table on of the following column items:

1. **DATE** (`java.sql.Date`)
2. **TIME** (`java.sql.Time`)
3. **TIMESTAMP** (`java.sql.Timestamp`)

Generally when we declare a `Date` field in the class and try to store it.
It will store as **TIMESTAMP** in the database.

```
@Temporal
private Date joinedDate;
```

Above code will store value looks like **08-07-17 04:33:35.870000000 PM**

If we want to store only the **DATE** in the database,
We can use/define `TemporalType`.

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date joinedDate;
```

This time, it would store **08-07-17** in database

There are some other attributes as well as `@Temporal` which can be used based on the requirement.

Comment: Default value is TemporalType.DATE. Have no idea why you've provided for non-annotated attribute value with time part.

Comment: if two dates are same there by will above aspect is working ( TemporalType.DATE ).

Comment: Don't do Copy Paste the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25333711/what-is-the-use-of-the-temporal-annotation-in-hibernate/25337628

Answer (score 12):

Temporal types are the set of time-based types that can be used in persistent state mappings.

The list of supported temporal types includes the three `java.sql` types `java.sql.Date`, `java.sql.Time`, and `java.sql.Timestamp`, and it includes the two `java.util` types `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar`.

The `java.sql` types are completely hassle-free. They act just like any other simple mapping type and do not need any special consideration.

The two `java.util` types need additional metadata, however, to indicate which of the JDBC `java.sql` types to use when communicating with the JDBC driver. This is done by annotating them with the `@Temporal` annotation and specifying the JDBC type as a value of the `TemporalType` enumerated type.

There are three enumerated values of DATE, TIME, and TIMESTAMP to represent each of the `java.sql` types.

Answer (score 7):

If you're looking for short answer:

In the case of using java.util.Date, Java doesn't really know how to directly relate to SQL types. This is when `@Temporal` comes into play. It's used to specify the desired SQL type.

Source: [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-date-time)

Answer (score 6):

I use Hibernate 5.2 and `@Temporal` is not required anymore.
*java.util.date*, *sql.date*, *time.LocalDate* are stored into DB with appropriate datatype as Date/timestamp.

Comment: then what is the solution if we only want to save date using Hibernate 5.x

Comment: Use of Java 8 LocalDate

Answer (score 5):

Simply, `@Temporal` is a Hibernate JPA annotation which should only be set on a java.util.Date or java.util.Calendar.
**It helps to convert the date and time values from Java object to compatible database type and will retrieve it back to the application.**

supports;

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
```

Comment: this doesn't add anything new to the existing answers!

Answer (score 3):

use this

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name="create_date")
private Calendar createDate;

public Calendar getCreateDate() {
    return createDate;
}

public void setCreateDate(Calendar createDate) {
    this.createDate = createDate;
}
```

Comment: this doesn't add anything new to the existing answers!

Answer (score 1):

We use @Temporal annotation to insert date, time or both in database table.Using TemporalType we can insert data, time or both int table.

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE) // insert date
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME) // insert time
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP) // insert  both time and date.
```

Comment: Thanks, but why should we use it?

Comment: this doesn't add anything new to the existing answers!