# Is TemporalType = Timestamp necessary if we want to store Date in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-annotations

Is it necessary to give `@Temporal`, if we want to store `Date` in Hibernate?

```
@Column(name = "Date_Open")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
public Date getDateOpen() {
  return this.dateOpen;
}
```

What will be default `TemporalType` if we do not use `@Temporal` annotation?

What will be default value if `@Temporal` is not given and what is benefit if it is given with `TemporalType.Timestamp`?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate without being a duplicate exactly xP... You will probably find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25333711/what-is-the-use-of-the-temporal-annotation-in-hibernate I will not vote it as a duplicate though

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the use of the @Temporal annotation in Hibernate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25333711/what-is-the-use-of-the-temporal-annotation-in-hibernate)

Comment: The `@Temporal` is used to specify the type that a JPA extension must persist for entity fields of type`java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar` only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Temporal not necessary to use with Date filed, by default hibernate save date with Timestamp, We can use the @Temporal annotation to specify the precision in which hibernate will save the date, time or timestamp. In plain Java APIs, the temporal precision of time is not defined. When dealing with temporal data, you might want to describe the expected precision in database.
following Type used to indicate a specific mapping of java.util.Date
or java.util.Calenda.

```
TemporalType.DATE: maps the date as java.sql.Date.
TemporalType.TIME: maps the date as java.sql.Time.
TemporalType.TIMESTAMP: maps the date as java.sql.Timestamp.
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25333711/what-is-the-use-of-the-temporal-annotation-in-hibernate) is nice explanation about @temporal

Also about Absence of @Temporal annotation in date field:

> In plain Java APIs, the temporal precision of time is not defined.
>   When dealing with temporal data you might want to describe the
>   expected precision in database. Temporal data can have DATE, TIME, or
>   TIMESTAMP precision (ie the actual date, only the time, or both). Use
>   the @Temporal annotation to fine tune that.
>
> [From 2.2.2.1. Declaring basic property mappings.](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-mapping-property)
>
> This might indicate that the actual date representation in the
>   database is not defined and to be sure it is better to specify it
>   directly.