# MySQL/JDBC/Hibernate Bad format for DATE '91' in column 19

Tags: mysql, hibernate

in model uses the date as type

```
@Column(name="birthdate")
private Date birtdate;
```

I got following exception when use date type in model user in spring boot application

```
Hibernate: select user0_.user_id as user_id1_1_, user0_.address as address2_1_, user0_.alt_isd as alt_isd3_1_, user0_.alt_no as alt_no4_1_, user0_.approved as approved5_1_, user0_.birthdate as birthdat6_1_, user0_.blood_group as blood_gr7_1_, user0_.ckey as ckey8_1_, user0_.comp_name as comp_nam9_1_, user0_.created_date as created10_1_, user0_.ctime as ctime11_1_, user0_.driverunderuser as driveru12_1_, user0_.email as email13_1_, user0_.emergencycontact0 as emergen14_1_, user0_.emergencycontact1 as emergen15_1_, user0_.emergencycontact2 as emergen16_1_, user0_.image as image17_1_, user0_.interval_time as interva18_1_, user0_.isd_code as isd_cod19_1_, user0_.last_name as last_na20_1_, user0_.driver_license_no as driver_21_1_, user0_.license_expiry_date as license22_1_, user0_.mobile as mobile23_1_, user0_.modified_date as modifie24_1_, user0_.name as name25_1_, user0_.password as passwor26_1_, user0_.status as status27_1_, user0_.user_confirmation as user_co28_1_, user0_.user_type as user_ty29_1_, user0_.user_name as user_na30_1_ from tbl_user user0_ where user0_.user_name=?
    2017-09-28 15:43:41.707  WARN 6844 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S1009
    2017-09-28 15:43:41.707 ERROR 6844 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : `Bad format for DATE '91' in column 19.`
    2017-09-28 15:43:41.719 ERROR 6844 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not execute query; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query] with root cause

    java.sql.SQLException: Bad format for DATE '91' in column 19.
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:964) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar:5.1.44]
```

Comment: please go through https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=32649

Comment: what column type you have used in table

Comment: date type  @DeedarAliBrohi

Answer (score 0):

please try

```
@Column(name="birthdate")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date birtdate;
```

see [What is the use of the @Temporal annotation in Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25333711/what-is-the-use-of-the-temporal-annotation-in-hibernate)