# java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'Hora de verano GMT' is unrecognized

Tags: java, mysql, maven, spring-boot

I use springboot, maven, connector:  mysql-connector-java-8.0.11 in local, system windows. I have this error,

> java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'Hora de verano GMT'
>   is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must
>   configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the serverTimezone
>   configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you
>   want to utilize time zone support.

I have modified in mysql file my.ini, I have put: timezone='UTC'. I have changed to mysql-connector-java-8.0.12, the same error. I have tried, 5.1.46, I have been other error.

Thank you

Comment: Please, show me your code. Check if you are using a prepared statement and setting the date correctly. What country is in the summer time?

Comment: I don't have code just entity with these declarations @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date updated_at;    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date created_at; and repository just insert without date

Comment: Have you tried @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)? Please check this -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25333711/what-is-the-use-of-the-temporal-annotation-in-hibernate

Comment: no, but in my dbb the type is Date, no  timestamp

Comment: You may check your MySQL configuration, since looks like you have summer time on that. It is possibly something native, not a Java mistake (just guessing).

Comment: Yes, looking on the internet I saw that it was a possibility, that's why I changed my.ini and I put timezone='UTC'. No change

Comment: What about this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930900/how-do-i-set-the-time-zone-of-mysql

Comment: SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone. The answer SYSTEM

Comment: Your system timezone is set to what locale?

Comment: In Java you can check using Locale currentLocale = Locale.getDefault(); , and then printout on the log or console.

Comment: Yes my system is local. I dont' arrive to start my aplication

Comment: return es_ES And I am not in Spain, now

Comment: That means your machine (windows) timezone is set to Spain. Set your Windows timezone and then restart your machine, it should work.

Comment: The language is spanish but timezone is Ireland in windows 10

Comment: When I am in Ireland, I have put in my.ini default-time-zone = 'IST', in spring boot @PostConstruct
   public void started(){
     // Setting Spring Boot SetTimeZone
  TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
   } in application properties spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone = IST, no change

Answer (score 8):

I found the answer.

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database?useSSL=false&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=passwprd
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

Thanks

Comment: Simply adding ?serverTimezone=UTC worked for me.