# Spring jpa util date

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

While using `java.util.Date` in a spring boot application, is it required to decorate with `@Temporal` annotation? For me, it worked without the annotation!

Can anyone clarify? As per my knowledge it needs to be decorated with the `@Temporal` annotation.

Comment: show your entity. And what version of hibernate are you using.

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding of the question, you want to know when it is necessary to use the `@Temporal` annotation, and when it is not.

- According to [this documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/Temporal.html), the annotation is used on `java.util` data types. I have been using `java.sql` date and time objects, and they do not require this annotation.
- The `@Temporal` annotation is a way of converting between java API for date and calendar information, and temporal types the database can understand. Please consult [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25333711/what-is-the-use-of-the-temporal-annotation-in-hibernate) for more info.

`java.util.Date` has date and time precision, and that is why you need to annotate it with `@Temporal` when persisting to a database data type of TIME or DATE.

> If you are persisting a `java.util.Date` object to a database data type of TIMESTAMP, then that is probably why it works, since both types have the same precision.

Comment: Did it answer your question? Please consider marking it as a correct one for future reference.